# Django - display image from static folder in accordance to values from DB

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `Django` app which has a model that holds cities, counties and countries codes:

**models.py**

```
class AreaMap(models.Model):
    Code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fCityCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='City', max_length=100)
    fCountyCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='County', max_length=100)
    fCountryCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Country', max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fCityCode
```

For each city, I have some static images in my static folder which are not going to be changed (or at least, if required, the old file would be overwritten with a new one but keeping the same filename). The correspondence between the image and the value from the database is by field 'fCityCode`:

**Example:**

For **New York** - in the database is saved as 'NewYork' and the image filename from my static folder is the same, 'NewYork'.

Now, I would like to display in my `HTML` template every image from the folder that corresponds to a value from the database.

I've done some research and I read that when it comes to static images is better to import them from the static folder rather than storing the images in the database which makes sense. Is there any way of doing this mapping and achieving this using `Django`? Thanks

**Later edit**

So, my `settings.py` looks as below:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

My `urls.py` looks as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
        #other urls
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The model above have been modified according to `foo-bar` answer and added the `@property` constructor:

```
class AreaMap(models.Model):
    Code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fCityCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='City', max_length=100)
    fCountyCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='County', max_length=100)
    fCountryCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Country', max_length=100, default='RO')

    @property
    def img_url(self):
        return "{}{}".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.fCityCode)
```

Using inspect option from the browser, this is how the `URL` of the photo looks like but somehow it is not displayed in the browser:

```
<a href="/path/" class="card img-card fh-400 border-0 outer-bg" data-background-inner="/media/NewYork.jpg">
<div class="inner-bg overlay-dark" style="background-image:url(&quot;/media/NewYork.jpg&quot;);">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the template code? Because the `&quot;` should not be there, you should have `'` char instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this files are fixed and won't be changed frequently, I think they should be stored in [**`static directory`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/). Now if the folder structure is like this:

```
.
├── project_root
├── static
│   ├── city_images
│      ├── LA.jpg
│      ├── NewYork.jpg
│      └── Washington.jpg
├── apps
```

Then your settings should be like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then simply use:

```
{% load static %}
<div class="inner-bg overlay-dark" style="background-image:url({% static 'city_images/NewYork.jpg' %};);">
```

Or you can integrate with your model like mentioned in your edit:

```
# model

from django.templatetags.static import static

class AreaMap(models.Model):
    Code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fCityCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='City', max_length=100)
    fCountyCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='County', max_length=100)
    fCountryCode = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Country', max_length=100, default='RO')

    @property
    def img_url(self):
        return static("city_images/{}".format(self.fCityCode))

# view

{% for i in areamap_objects %}
   <img src="{{ i.img_url }}" >
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was needed. I cannot award the bounty now - only in about 10h from now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there !!
According to your settings, your directory structure should be like this,

```
.
├── project_root
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── foo
└── myapp_name
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── templates
    │   └── sample.html
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Key Point is the **`media`** directory should be placed in the root director

To render the images in your template, you need to pass the **`AreaMap`** queryset to the template through view.

```
#myapp_name/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render


def sample_view(request):
    return render(request, 'sample.html', context={'qs': AreaMap.objects.all()})
```

and now iterate (or whatever you want to do in your template) the Queryset in the template as,

```
#myapp_name/templates/sample.html

{% for item in qs %}
    <p><img src="{{ item.img_url }}" width="300px"></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I up-voted the answer thanks to your effort and your explanation. I read that using `MEDIA-ROOT` is only to be used in development, not in production, which is why I accepted the answer of ruddra. Cheers!

Comment: That's great. But, can I have a reference to which says *MEDIA-ROOT* isn't for production? @cdrrr